# ubuntu 18.04 gramps package does not install with synaptic package manager

Tags: package-management, synaptic

I am using ubuntu 18.04 with synaptic package manager, and the "gramps" package is available. When I try to install several several command lines are broken such as

W: Failed to fetch http://ny-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/osm-gps-map/libosmgpsmap-1.0-1_1.1.0-2_amd64.deb

The version of gramps is 4.2.8~dfsg-1_all.deb

Comment: "Failed to fetch" is a network or server error, not an apt error. Try a different mirror.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the mirror and the package downloaded.